# laminating cherry to pine or ash

Tags: design, wood-selection, wood-movement

I want to make bedposts about 6" square. I want to laminate cherry to the outside and wonder about the core. I thought I would use pine or ash as a core. worried about the expansion of the inner core splitting the cherry laminate. any suggestions would be appreciated.  thanks

Comment: Cherry veneer, or thicker? If thicker, I can't think of why you'd need a core.

Comment: Well FWIW veneered furniture of old often had pine or another similar softwood as a core. More recently, blockboard and similar board materials do the same thing. So there's plenty of precedent both in terms of quality furniture and material aimed at a more utilitarian level. Now that said, you want to pick the pieces of wood for the cores with care so there's minimum chance of them moving/distorting (e.g. avoid boxed heart). Given the nature of wood supplies these days one way around being so picky is to laminate them up yourself, and the laminated pieces are v. likely to be far more stable.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, *"If thicker, I can't think of why you'd need a core"* weight alone? Strength for mounting? Really large range of possible thicknesses here between veneer (esp. modern stuff) and full board thicknesses like 3/4" so I don't think it's a binary choice.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific about "thicker"... I was thinking of something like a 3/4" actual stock. And while everything depends on hardware, but I wouldn't expect mounting issues with 3/4" hardwood.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, yes 3/4 actual would be very strong, but I worry since this is just cherry rather than e.g. oak or something stronger still. It could be fine without any core, but myself I'd want to at least reinforce the mounting positions internally if I went with a hollow leg.